# Html5 video isn't loading in safari(mac) browser

Tags: safari, html5-video

Html5 video is not streaming in safari(mac) browser.
here's the code

```
<%= video_tag(['filepath/banner-video.mp4'], :width => '100%', :autoplay => true, :loop => true, :type => 'video/mp4') %>
```

It works fine in chrome/FF. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In Chrome/FF is there ability to rewind video in player or its grayed?

Comment: Maybe the video uses a codec that Safari can't play?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk it works fine in chrome/FF no problem..

Comment: @Wukerplank How can i fix that?